# Get Error 530 5.7.0 Authentication Required when sending email using Django Python

Tags: python, smtp

I am trying to send emails with G-Suite account using python in Django. As Google stoped the less secure App option for the new applications, I have to use Oauth2. 
But when I start to send emails via smtplib, the ERROR:

```
smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused: (530, b'5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n5.7.0  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError q4sm8418287pfl.175 - gsmtp'
```

And after looking up the reference, it means "530, "5.7.0", Must issue a STARTTLS command first."
However, I have added "server.starttls()". Could someone help me? Many thanks.

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', port=587)
server.ehlo('test')
server.starttls()
server.docmd('AUTH', 'XOAUTH2 ' + base64.b64encode(auth_string.encode()).decode("utf-8"))
server.sendmail(from_addr, to_addr, msg.as_string())
server.quit()
```

Comment: You should go to https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError and read what gmail wants to let you use their SMTP server.

Answer (score 4):

Per this [https://stackabuse.com/how-to-send-emails-with-gmail-using-python/#:~:text=As%20for%20the%20actual%20Python,com'%2C%20465)%20server.](https://stackabuse.com/how-to-send-emails-with-gmail-using-python/#:%7E:text=As%20for%20the%20actual%20Python,com%27%2C%20465)%20server.), you probably have 2-step verification turned on.

To enable your web apps to send SMTP's from/to your gmail, you will need to create an app-specific password for less secure apps.

1. Go to your Google Account.
2. Select Security.
3. Under "Signing in to Google," select App Passwords. You may need to
   sign in. If you don’t have this option, it might be because: 2-Step
   Verification is not set up for your account. 2-Step Verification is
   only set up for security keys. Your account is through work, school,
   or other organization. You turned on Advanced Protection.
4. At the bottom, choose Select app and choose
   the app you are using and then Select device and choose the device
   you’re using and then Generate.
5. Take this 16-character code in the yellow bar and place it in your
   environment variables as your "EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD"

Comment: from number 4 above, when you get to "Select the app and device you want to generate the app password for." you need to click on "Other (customers name)" and in "Select Device" choose  "Other (customers name)". Then since you're using this to send email, you specify the url or your website eg. http://mywebsite.com. Then click on "GENERATE". Then use the 16 character code generated in your code, and or Heroku config variables as necessary

Answer (score 0):

```
EMAIL_BACKEND="django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_HOST_USER ='youremail@gmail.com' 
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'yourpassword'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Add this on your settings. After that :

```
python manage.py shell
```

You will enter to Python shell. Then:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
```

Write this command on shell and after that:

```
send_mail(
    "django test mail",
    "this is django test mail",
    "your.email@gmail.com",
    "recipient.email@example.com",
    fail_silently=False
)
```

If output is equal to:

> 1

, then you send email through your Gmail.

Comment: I did this, but I recive the error smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.  The username and password are corrects.